# error on npm start for react empty project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, terminal

I tried to create an empty react project based on typescript for learning using Visual Studio Code

I try to use this guide: https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/create-react-app-typescript

I got this error: on the cmd line: npm run start

```
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\hed\Desktop\reactTest2\my-app2\src'
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './App' in 'C:\Users\hed\Desktop\reactTest2\my-app2\src'

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 8:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './reportWebVitals' in 'C:\Users\hed\Desktop\reactTest2\my-app2\src'

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

[image]

But, my folder looks like that :

[image]

look like : reportWebVitals.ts and App.tsx are exist

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not exporting `App` from `App.tsx`, make sure to check for exports and imports.

Comment: I think its should create a full empty working projet without any change..

Comment: Have you found what was causing that?.

Comment: No, I just leave it alone for now